# Average value of numbers from N to 1000 (included), without even numbers which are divisible by 6 and 17

Tags: c, loops, average

First I have to input N, N becomes the first number to be checked.

Input: 79

Output should be: 537.70.

```
int sum=0;
      while(1)
        {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n>=10 && n<80)
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("New output:\n");
    }

for(i=n;i<=1000;i++)
{
    if(i%2==0 && i%6!=0 && i%17!=0)
    {
        sum+=i;
    }
```

I didnt put (float)sum/N to get average because I'm doing something wrong with sum.

More input output:

Input: 10 Output: 505.21

Input: 44 Output: 521.18

Comment: without even numbers that are divisible by 6 and 17

Comment: Do you want to exclude even numbers which are divisible by either 6 or 17, or those which are divisible by 102?

Comment: Answer is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as keeping a 'running sum', you also need to keep a count of *how many* numbers were used, so you can properly calculate the average:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter start number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int sum = 0, count = 0;
    for (int i = n; i <= 1000; ++i) {
        if (!(i % 2) && (i % 6) && (i % 17)) {
            sum += i;
            ++count;
        }
    }
    printf("Average is: %.2f\n", (double)sum / (double)count);
    return 0;
}
```

> Input: 79
>   Output should be: 537.70.

Are you sure about this value? I get 538.70 - but I get the given values for the other test cases you cite.

Comment: Yes 538.70 is correct, I made mistake with not adding counter because i divide it with N and not with counter.Thanks for ur answer